# How to Deploy any ERC-20 Smart Contract using Safe-Core SDK from Safe Address(gas less)

Tags: erc-20, safe-core, gasless, deploy

> How to Deploy any ERC-20 Smart Contract using Safe-Core SDK from Safe
> Address(gas less)

Answer (score 1):

To deploy any contract from a Safe, you need to create a transaction that calls the [CreateCall](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol) contract that is deployed on these addresses depending on the network: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/create_call.json

Once you have the transaction data ready, you can execute it gaslessly with the Relay Kit with Gelato: https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/relay-kit